# Error with Express on AppFog but not in local

Tags: node.js, express, jsdom, appfog

I get an error when I host my app on AppFog. Line 50, when I call JSDOM... The issue doesn't appear in local, I don't understand why it doesn't work in remote...

My code (works in local):

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    Creation.findAll({where: "state = 1",order: 'id DESC', limit: 2}).success( function(creations) {
        Post.findAll({where: "state = 1",order: 'id DESC', limit: 2}).success(function(posts){
            async.map(posts, function(postEntity, callback){
                jsdom.env( // PROBLEM HERE
                    postEntity.content,
                    ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
                    function(errors, window) {
                        if(errors) return callback(errors);
                        postEntity.content = window.$("p").text();
                        callback(null, postEntity);
                    }
                );
            }, function(err, transformedPosts){
                if(err) return callback(err);
                res.render('index', {
                    creations: creations,
                    posts: transformedPosts,
                    title: "Anthony Cluse | Portfolio"
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
```

My error (on AppFog - I sent a request to the support):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'implementation' of undefined
at exports.env.exports.jsdom.env.processHTML (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1-  0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:178:59)
at Object.exports.env.exports.jsdom.env (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1-   0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:269:5)
at exports.index.Creation.findAll.success.Post.findAll.success.async.map.res.render.creations (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1- 0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/routes/index.js:50:23)
at _asyncMap (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1-0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:222:13)
at async.each (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1-0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:99:13)
at Array.forEach (native)
at _each (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1-0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)
at async.each (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1-0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:98:9)
at _asyncMap (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1-0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:221:9)
at Object.doParallel [as map] (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1- 0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:199:23)
```

Logs on AppFog:

```
====> /logs/staging.log <====

# Logfile created on 2013-02-22 23:41:12 +0000 by logger.rb/25413
Skipping npm support: npm-shrinkwrap.json is not provided

====> /logs/stdout.log <====

Express server listening on port 56643
Executing: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Posts` (`slug` VARCHAR(255), `title` VARCHAR(255), `thumbnail` VARCHAR(255), `content` TEXT, `state` INTEGER, `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Creations` (`slug` VARCHAR(255), `screenshot` VARCHAR(255), `title` VARCHAR(255), `subtitle` VARCHAR(255), `url` VARCHAR(255), `content` TEXT, `webdesigner` VARCHAR(255), `developper` VARCHAR(255), `integrator` VARCHAR(255), `designer` VARCHAR(255), `state` INTEGER, `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Posts` (`slug` VARCHAR(255), `title` VARCHAR(255), `thumbnail` VARCHAR(255), `content` TEXT, `state` INTEGER, `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Creations` (`slug` VARCHAR(255), `screenshot` VARCHAR(255), `title` VARCHAR(255), `subtitle` VARCHAR(255), `url` VARCHAR(255), `content` TEXT, `webdesigner` VARCHAR(255), `developper` VARCHAR(255), `integrator` VARCHAR(255), `designer` VARCHAR(255), `state` INTEGER, `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing: SELECT * FROM `Creations` WHERE state = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2;
Executing: SELECT * FROM `Posts` WHERE state = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2;
{ __options: 
   { timestamps: true,
     instanceMethods: {},
     classMethods: {},
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: false,
     underscored: false,
     syncOnAssociation: true,
     paranoid: false,
     omitNull: false,
     hasPrimaryKeys: false },
  hasPrimaryKeys: false,
  selectedValues: 
   { slug: 'my-first-post',
     title: 'my first post',
     thumbnail: 'http://i.pcworld.fr/1151321-espace-sfr.jpg',
     content: '<p>\r\nun content pour le premier post\r\n</p>\r\n<img src="http://i.pcworld.fr/1151321-espace-sfr.jpg">\r\n<p>et la suite !!!</p>',
     state: 1,
     id: 1,
     createdAt: Thu Feb 21 2013 21:45:58 GMT+0000 (UTC),
     updatedAt: Thu Feb 21 2013 21:46:00 GMT+0000 (UTC) },
  slug: 'my-first-post',
  title: 'my first post',
  thumbnail: 'http://i.pcworld.fr/1151321-espace-sfr.jpg',
  content: '<p>\r\nun content pour le premier post\r\n</p>\r\n<img src="http://i.pcworld.fr/1151321-espace-sfr.jpg">\r\n<p>et la suite !!!</p>',
  state: 1,
  id: 1,
  createdAt: Thu Feb 21 2013 21:45:58 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  updatedAt: Thu Feb 21 2013 21:46:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  isNewRecord: false }

====> /logs/staging.log <====

# Logfile created on 2013-02-22 23:41:12 +0000 by logger.rb/25413
Skipping npm support: npm-shrinkwrap.json is not provided

====> /logs/stdout.log <====

Express server listening on port 48140
Executing: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Posts` (`slug` VARCHAR(255), `title` VARCHAR(255), `thumbnail` VARCHAR(255), `content` TEXT, `state` INTEGER, `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Creations` (`slug` VARCHAR(255), `screenshot` VARCHAR(255), `title` VARCHAR(255), `subtitle` VARCHAR(255), `url` VARCHAR(255), `content` TEXT, `webdesigner` VARCHAR(255), `developper` VARCHAR(255), `integrator` VARCHAR(255), `designer` VARCHAR(255), `state` INTEGER, `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Posts` (`slug` VARCHAR(255), `title` VARCHAR(255), `thumbnail` VARCHAR(255), `content` TEXT, `state` INTEGER, `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Creations` (`slug` VARCHAR(255), `screenshot` VARCHAR(255), `title` VARCHAR(255), `subtitle` VARCHAR(255), `url` VARCHAR(255), `content` TEXT, `webdesigner` VARCHAR(255), `developper` VARCHAR(255), `integrator` VARCHAR(255), `designer` VARCHAR(255), `state` INTEGER, `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Edit with Cheerio:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'), $;

exports.index = function(req, res) {
    Creation.findAll({where: "state = 1",order: 'id DESC', limit: 2}).success( function(creations) {
        Post.findAll({where: "state = 1",order: 'id DESC', limit: 2}).success(function(posts){
            async.map(posts, function(postEntity, callback){
                $ = cheerio.load(postEntity.content);
                postEntity.content = $("p").text();
                /*
                jsdom.env(
                    postEntity.content,
                    ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
                    function(errors, window) {
                        //deal with errors
                        if(errors) return callback(errors);
                        postEntity.content = window.$("p").text();
                        callback(null, postEntity);
                    }
                );
                */
            }, function(err, transformedPosts){
                if(err) return callback(err);
                res.render('index', {
                    creations: creations,
                    posts: transformedPosts,
                    title: "Anthony Cluse | Portfolio"
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: can you log the content of postEntity?  Is data in your AppFog database correct?

Comment: I can't to see AppFog logs. I have to send an email to the support for get logs...

Comment: But in local, postEntity is correct.

Comment: `af logs appname --all` should work.

Comment: if postEntity is correct locally, this means the code is likely ok, and the database too.  So this leaves the database content on appfog.  If the data is also ok, this could be a problem with jsdom, but you should check this first.

Comment: Yes thank you. See logs below. But there is no error I don't understand. My website : http://anthonycluse.aws.af.cm

Comment: you should add the logs in your question, not as an answer.

Comment: Ok I updated my subject. Is there a problem with JSDOM and AppFog?

Comment: yes, this seems to be the case.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears jsdom relies on a native library that does not work on CloudFoundry, same thing AppFog uses.

see this jsdom isssue https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/436

workaround would be to use something like cheerio (https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio)

Here's an example from the home page:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var $ = cheerio.load('<h2 class = "title">Hello world</h2>');

$('h2.title').text('Hello there!');
$('h2').addClass('welcome');
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but I'm a beginner in Node JS, could you give me an example with my code? That seems to be difficult for me.

Comment: try cheerio instead, looks much simpler.

Comment: I updated my subject, I tried with Cheerio but there is no response. The page doesn't load.

Comment: looks like you forgot to call `callback(null, postEntity);`

Comment: Wow yes thank you so much. I hosted my App and now it works. I'm so happy. Thank you so much. My last issue is about sessions, sometimes they destroy alone, maybe I have to add more memory for the App... But I know I have to create a new subject :-) Maybe I will contact the support.